# What are the conditions when sometimes Required field validators fails in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

There is a strange problem in my application. There is one mandatory field which we are making mandatory through Required field validator but still in few scenarios it fails. Can someone tell me what can be the possible causes. I am not able to recreate this issue.

Comment: Can you provide some more info, what type of control are you trying to validate?

Comment: Explain what you mean by 'fails' (are you getting an error message, does the control not validate properly) and explain in what specific scenarios you have seen this happen. Otherwise this simply cannot be answered satisfactorily.

Comment: I am using text box where i put a date through calender. I am not getting an error message but it sends null to database that causes the problem.

Comment: We need more info, what calendar control are you using, are you using the built-in textbox from the calendar control or your own? And are you *sure* you cannot consistently reproduce this in any way? That's hard to believe. And show us some declarative markup of the calendar control and required field validator so we may be able to help.

Comment: I am very sure its not getting recreated everytime. Out of 500  there are just 2 time s it failed. We are using normal calender control.

Comment: Calendar:  
              <img src="../_Images/btn_calendar.gif" id="imgDateOriginalDocDue" title="Pick Date from Calendar"
                    alt="Select Date" align="middle" runat="server" />

Required Field Validator:
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvorigdocduedate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateOriginalDocDue"
                    ErrorMessage="Original document due date" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: Show us the code! Server-side submit/click event as well please. And stick it in your question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone disables JavaScript, and you're not using `Page.IsValid` in your server side code, then you might encounter empty fields.

This should do:

```
void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        return;

    // Do form stuff
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is enabled. i have tested it in both scenarios.

Comment: It's still a good idea to check `Page.IsValid` if you're not doing so. There might be other reasons why the client side validation is not working properly, although it is actually very reliable (unless someone deliberately circumvents it).

Comment: @Thorarin: Agreed, definitely good practice and in this case it could well be some scenario going on where a client side error occurs (for whatever reason) and the server code ends up being executed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to validate a dropdownlist with a "Please select" option, with a value of "-1" for example, you will need to set the initial value property of the validation control to this value to ensure that another choice has been made.

Comment: Why are you guessing? Besides this can be reproduced consistently, so it likely isn't the right answer.